# Multiple XMLRootElement after JAXB Marshalling

Tags: jaxb

I have the following classes with jax-ws webservice;

Interface Class (myserviceInt.java);

```
@WebService(name="myservice")
@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC)
public interface myserviceInt {
@WebMethod(action="urn:OutIn", operationName="ACCT")
public String getACCT(
        @WebParam(partName="Prod1")String prod1, 
        @WebParam(partName="Prod2")String prod2);

}
```

Implementation Class (myserviceImpl.java);

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "path.to.webservice.myserviceInt", portName="acct", serviceName="acctservice", targetNamespace="http://demo.acctservice.com/")
public class myserviceImpl implements myserviceInt {


@Override
public String getACCT(String prod1, String prod1){

Other codes

String id = "25";
String description = "The Third Product"
ACCTResponse acct = new ACCTResponse();

acct.setId(id);
acct.setDescription(description);
String XMLstring = acct.ACCTResponseBeanToXML(acct);
return XMLstring;

}

}
```

ACCTResponse Class (ACCTResponse.java);

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name="ACCTResponse")
public class ACCTResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "ID")
    private String id;
    @XmlElement(name = "Description")
    private String description;

... their setters and getters;

}
```

The Marshaller Class (ACCTUtil.java);

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import path.to.responseclass.ACCTResponse;

public class ACCTUtil {


    public static String ACCTResponseBeanToXML(ACCTResponse acct)
    {
        String responseStr = null;
        try
        {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ACCTResponse.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            m.marshal(acct, writer);
            responseStr = writer.toString();
            int xmlHeaderIndex = responseStr.indexOf("?>");
            if(xmlHeaderIndex > 0)
                responseStr = responseStr.substring(xmlHeaderIndex + 2, responseStr.length());

        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return responseStr;
    }
}
```

every other libraries needed were left out to save time. I also have the package-info.java in the respective path for the ACCTResponse.java to add the required response namespaceURI and prefix.

Now, I got the following as response after Marshalling as described above;

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:ACCTResponse xmlns:ns2="http://demo.acctservice.com/">
         <return><![CDATA[<net:ACCTResponse xmlns:net="http://demo.acctservice.com/">
    <net:ID>25</net:ID>
    <net:Description>The Third Product</net:Description>
    </net:ACCTResponse>]]></return>
      </ns2:ACCTResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

The response I want to achieve for a consumer of this webservice that have a fixed client is this;

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org /soap/envelope/">
   <saop:Body>
    <net:ACCTResponse xmlns:net="http://demo.acctservice.com/">    
    <net:ID>25</net:ID>
    <net:Description>The Third Product</net:Description>
    </net:ACCTResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What modifications/manipulations do I need, to achieve this response from my codes. Thanks.